# ProfileViewController.m trying to getProfilePicture

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, picturebox, user-profile

I have a profile view controller where the user can set or change his or her profile picture but am getting constant errors that do not make sense to me.

```
-(void)getProfilePicture
{
    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    NSLog(@"file--%@",[user objectForKey:PF_USER_PICTURE]);

    userName = user[PF_USER_USERNAME];
    status = user[PF_USER_STATUS];

    if ([user objectForKey:PF_USER_PICTURE]) {
        [imageUser setFile:[user objectForKey:PF_USER_PICTURE]];
        [imageUser loadInBackground];
    }
    else{
        imageUser.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blank_profile@2x.png"];
    }


//    fieldName.text = user[PF_USER_FULLNAME];
}

#pragma mark - UIActionSheetDelegate
```

Any help would be much appreciated or any supporting code thats needed, thanks.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: "No visible interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector 'setFile:'

"No visible interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector 'loadInBackground'

Comment: You have an object, that from the errors you receiving, I understand that it is of type `UIImageView`, and you try to call `setFile:` and `loadInBackground` methods on it. `UIImageView` does not respond to any of the above methods. Perhaps you are calling it on the wrong object.....